# How to add unit tests to CKEditor custom plugins

Tags: unit-testing, plugins, ckeditor5

I have made an initial custom plugin for CKEditor, but it's not obvious from the CKEditor documentation what is the best way to structure a custom plugin project or how to add unit tests.

I want to set up the project so that it follows good practices (like Test Driven Development) as I keep developing it, and possibly add it into a CI/CD pipeline.

**Current setup**

My custom plugin adds subject tags for the topic of a sentence.

I based it on the inline widget tutorial (which creates a Classic Editor v29 application with a local custom plugin added in) - https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/tutorials/implementing-an-inline-widget.html

```
|---app.js
|---index.html
|---node_modules/
|---package.json
|---subject/
|---|---subject.js
|---|---subjectcommand.js
|---|---subjectediting.js
|---|---subjectui.js
|---webpack.config.js
```

**Test suite**

The CKEditor Testing Environment documentation says that the `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-tests` package can be used outside `ckeditor5` - https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/contributing/testing-environment.html

So I rearranged the plugin directories to separate out `src` and `tests`:

```
|---app.js
|---index.html
|---node_modules/
|---package.json
|---subject/
|---|---src/
|---|---|---subject.js
|---|---|---subjectcommand.js
|---|---|---subjectediting.js
|---|---|---subjectui.js
|---|---tests/
|---|---|---subject.js
|---webpack.config.js
```

Then ran the test suite:

```
node ./node_modules/.bin/ckeditor5-dev-tests --files=*
```

But it looks like the `ckeditor5-dev-tests` package might only test plugins that are part of the CKEditor software (e.g. when you are contributing to the CKEditor project itself). All the `--files` option glob conversions map to `node_modules/ckeditor5-*` See: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev/tree/master/packages/ckeditor5-dev-tests#rules-for-converting---files-option-to-glob-pattern

**Question**

I'm not sure if I'm using the testing suite wrong, or if I am taking the wrong approach in the project structure - maybe the project should just be for the plugin by itself (without `app.js`, etc.), then add it to the Classic Editor later somehow?